# Bee-attracting tall shrub with cones of tiny cream-white flowers in Colorado?

Tags: identification, shrubs, bee-attractive

We live at 7000 feet and have a volunteer shrub that is over 6 feet tall. The flowers are about 1/4"-3/8"; cream/white colored; with 5 wee petals and a pale yellow, spikey center. Also, the flowers are clumped in cones of about 8 rows.

The flowers are lightly scented, very pleasing to the nose. The bees love it.

I thought it might be some kind of a lilac or butterfly bush or butterfly weed?

[image: creamwhite shrub flower closeup]

[image: creamwhite shrub flower branches]

Comment: Prunus variety, yes - evergreen or not?

Comment: Goes dormant in winter; not an evergreen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's in the *Prunus subg. Padus* commonly known as bird cherries, chock cherry, hackberry, hagberry,  Mayday tree.  Don't think it is *Prunus maackii* because of the yellow center to the blooms in your picture; "maacki" is pure white.  It could be *Prunus virginiana* which is native and of which you are at the edge of its range.What elevation are you at?  A few species can exist at Colorado's elevation.  There is a number of Prunus plants in this category, and without a shot of the bark of the trunk, it's impossible to be sure.

Comment: We are at 7,000 feet. Since posting the pix, all the blooms have died. It's only early June, so I am hoping it's a rebloomer!

Comment: Prunus virginiana could survive at 7K feet.